# Questions regarding the convergence of Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

Consider a countable union of open pairwise disjoint intervals $A = \displaystyle\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty I_k$ with $a, b \in A$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \left[\frac{\mathrm d^n f(x)}{\mathrm dx^n}\right]_{x=a} \frac{(x-a)^n}{n!} \to f(x)$, pointwise and for all real $x \in A$, as $n \to \infty$.

Is this equivalent to $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \left[\frac{\mathrm d^n f(x)}{\mathrm dx^n}\right]_{x=b} \frac{(x-b)^n}{n!} \to f(x)$ where $b\neq a$, pointwise and for all real $x \in A$, as $n \to \infty$?

We could also imagine $A$ being just *one* open set $A = (x_0, x_1)$ or the whole real line $A = \mathbb R$. For example, the Maclaurin expansion for $\frac{1}{1+x}$ and $\sin(x)$ satisfies the two latter cases of being pointwise convergent $\forall x\in A$.

EDIT: As noted in the comments, $f \in \mathcal C^\infty(A)$ since the Taylor series requires all derivatives to exist.

Comment: You haven't told us what $f$ is. It just sort of appears out of nowhere in that first series.

Comment: @zhw. Any smooth function that satisfies the convergence constrain, I guess.

Comment: So assume $f\in C^\infty(A)?$ If so, you should say so.

Comment: @zhw. Since the nth derivative appears in the expression taken to a limit as $n\to\infty$, I assumed it would be obvious that $f\in\mathcal C^\infty$.